# All of a sudden my Manage Catalog page gives error (magento)

Tags: magento

When I go to `Catalog>Manage Categories` I am getting a page error:

```
There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 1377949846435
```

When I check the error log it says this:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:124:"Source model "ultramegamenu/category_attribute_source_block_proportions" not found for attribute "umm_cat_block_proportions"";i:1;s:4064:"#0 /var/www/vhosts/colorvaleactions.com/includes/src/__default.php(51239): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Source model "u...')
#1 /var/www/vhosts/colorvaleactions.com/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form.php(201): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getSource()
...
#28 {main}";s:3:"url";s:80:"/index.php/admin123/catalog_category/index/key/844ef758d7755189c954d467018f2a83/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: It looks like the autoloader is failing to load a file with a module named "ultramegamenu". Check your SITE_ROOT/app/code/[local/community]/Infortis/UltraMegamenu/Model/Category/Attribute/Source and make sure that that the file Proportions.php exists.

Answer (score 2):

Have removed the ultramegamenu from your magento installation ? If it is so then to solve this problem you need to delete the umm attributes from the table eav_attributes as well.

Comment: Same problem here, was able to solve it like this, thanks!